# Como buscar registros até o mês anterior?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Preciso pegar todos os dados, desde o inicio até o mês anterior, essa consulta tem que ser dinâmica, não posso colocar uma data fixa, pois no mês que vem precisaremos consultar novamente...

Em resumo, hoje preciso pegar todos os dados até o dia 28/02/2021 e no mês que vem até o dia 31/03/2021 e assim por diante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ... where DATEPART(m, _DATA_ ) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

Extrai o mês da data

> DATEPART(m, *DATA* )

e compara diminuindo um mês da data atual

> DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))